# ASP.net MVC SecretManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.net MVC 5.2 project on a macOS Sierra (not my choice unfortunately) and I am trying to set the client secrets with the SecretManager. I have tried running

```
dotnet user-secrets set Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerKey <consumer-key>
```

but I get that

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-user-secrets"
```

I executed the command in the project root and after googling the problem, apparently I need to run the command in the same folder as the *project.json* which I cannot find in my project structure. (do I need to create it manually?)

I apologise in advance for these beginner questions but I am just getting on board with the .net framework. 
Any tips/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know now projects use .csproj files instead of project.json, so you have to use it in the folder containing .csproj file

Judging from your project structure I guess it's "TwitterMania" folder - the one nested inside another "TwitterMania" folder